# How to format endnotemark

Tags: superscripts, xltxtra

I'm trying to get «real» superscript figures to the numbering of endnotes. It was quite straightforward loading the `xltxtra` package, but it isn't working when I change all footnotes to endnotes.

So, the question is: how can I define the `\endnotemark` so that it «loads» the superscripts from the font (in case it has)?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote
\let\footnotemark\endnotemark
\begin{document}
A\textsuperscript{1} \footnote{A}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image: No real superscripts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?  I kept digging deeper with `\meaning` until I found the root, which in this case was the definition of `\@makeenmark`.  The original definition is commented above the revised definition.

The problem is that `\@textsuperscript` is defined to go into math mode to set the box and the font in math mode is different.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote
\let\footnotemark\endnotemark
\makeatletter
%\def\@makeenmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@theenmark}}}
\def\@makeenmark{\hbox{\normalfont\textsuperscript{\@theenmark}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
A\textsuperscript{1} \footnote{A}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can attest that it works as well without the '\makeatletter' with '\def\makeenmark{\hbox{\normalfont\textsuperscript{\theenmark}}}'